# Pyspark Avoid Pivot Transformation To Dataframe - Pivot Alternative

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, pyspark, pivot

I have a datafrane to which I am applying a pivot transformation and I want to know if there is a way to have the same end result and avoid the pivot transformation.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
|gender|         pro|week|        share|forecast|
+------+------------+----+-------------+--------+
|  Male|           A|  40|          0.2|   195.0|
|Female|           A|  40|         0.01|    38.0|
|  Male|           B|  40|         0.15|   733.0|
|Female|           B|  41|         0.15|   579.0|
|Female|           C|  41|         0.01|    38.0|
```

The expected output os the following:

```
|gender|      pro|week|    share_1|    share_10|    share_15|    share_20|
+------+---------+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|  Male|        A|  40|        0.0|         0.0|         0.0|       195.0|
|Female|        A|  40|       38.0|         0.0|         0.0|         0.0|
|Female|        B|  41|        0.0|         0.0|       579.0|         0.0|
|Female|        C|  41|       38.0|         0.0|         0.0|         0.0|
|  Male|        B|  40|      191.0|       205.0|       733.0|       245.0|
```

At the moment I am implementing this:

```
df.groupBy(['gender','pro','week']).pivot("share").agg(first('forecast')).withColumnRenamed('0.01', 'share_1').withColumnRenamed('0.1', 'share_10').withColumnRenamed('0.15', 'share_15').withColumnRenamed('0.2', 'share_20')
```

Is there a have the same result without applying a pivot transformation?

Comment: you're having the best solution. What is bothering you with your current solution ?

Comment: I want to avoid the pivot transformation. Is it possible?

Comment: OK, but why ? what is the reason you want to avoid pivot ? Without a good reason, we cannot offer a proper solution. We need to fix a problem, like performance, or execution fail ....

Comment: Pivot provides poor performance with big datasets, that is the reason I want to avoid it.

Comment: performances are poor because you do not provide values for the `share` column - cf. doc  [`pivot(pivot_col, values=None)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) - more concise but less efficient, because Spark needs to first compute the list of distinct values internally. I can insure you that the current implementation of `pivot` will always be better than anything you'll try by yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Did that change and got improvement in speed :)

Comment: And therefore, you see that explaining the reason of your question was the key to a proper answer. Asking a good question is focusing on the problem - what is bothering you. If you start focusing on solution within the question, you'll end up with a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

performances are poor because you do not provide values for the **share** column.

cf. doc [`pivot(pivot_col, values=None)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot)

Not providing values is more concise but less efficient, because Spark needs to first compute the list of distinct values internally.

I can insure you that the current official implementation of pivot will always be better than anything you'll try by yourself. Just add your values and it will be good.